# Does Android have any networking limitations comparing to Linux?

Tags: android, linux, networking, linux-kernel

I have just read the following in *["The Growth of Android in Embedded Systems"](http://training.linuxfoundation.org/free-linux-training/download-training-materials/growth-of-android-in-embedded-systems)* [(PDF)](http://storage.pardot.com/6342/90356/lft_pub_growth_of_android.pdf) by Benjamin Zores of Linux Foundation:

> Last but not least, Android has deliberately hobbled one of Linux’s key assets when developing the networking and connectivity layer. The OS is unable to handle more than one network connection at a time, more than one device driver at a time (per connection type), and unable to handle more than one interface per connection type.

I am not able to find any other reference to this. What exactly does this mean?

Answer (score 5):

The Android developers saved time and money by:

- Only allowing a network connection to one network at a time, e.g. you can't route IP traffic to a connected WiFi network and a 3G network simultaneously.
- Only allowing one network device driver to run at any point in time per connection type. So you might have one driver for 3G networking, another for WiFi networking, another for USB tethering, but you can't load two separate WiFi drivers at once.
- Not supporting multiple logical interfaces for a single physical network. In Linux you might have `eth0` and `net0` pointing to the same NIC, but Android doesn't support this.

These network features are fundamental for desktop and server OSes, but were seen as unnecessary on mobile systems and were therefore sacrificed.